# Fortran- about command <<write>>

Tags: fortran90

i'm not very good with programming but i'm learning how to write a code in fortran with parallel studio XE 2011 with VS2010. So, my question is how can i use the backslash ( \ ) with command <> to stay in the  changing the line in dos??????

Example:

```
write(*,25) A(i,j)
   .
   . 
   .
25 format(4x,i5)
```

Comment: with command write without changing the line

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep the output on a single line while looping through `i` and `j`, the solution is

```
    write(*,25,advance='no') A(i,j)
```

If this is not what you want, please give more information so that we can better help you.